# Power management issues on an Asus N55

Tags: 12.04, power-management, overheating, acpi, fancontrol

I noticed that with respect to Win7 on my Asus N55 Ubuntu 12.04 tend to overheat the system. After startup the fan controller takes control of the fan, I could here it slowing down, after a few second following a login the fan increases its speed again. Though there are no processor hungry process: top shows only Xorg consuming 4%. Even with the system monitor the CPUs load look ok. Is it a power management related problem?

This can cause battery life troubles in general, and electronics is never happy to be overheated.

Is there a better tool to root the cause of the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for the feedback.

After a few more hours of hacking I concluded that the problem is the graphics card not being properly configured: It wasn't recognized until yesterday's update where I have seen a new Nvida_connect driver.

Now if I lspci I see the card as a GTX 555 card while the one on my laptop is a newer GT635M. If I play around with the /etc/X11/ config files the display gets messed up.

The heating problem is probably due to a bad initialization of the GPU.
My conclusion is that I should wait for NVidia to release the proper drivers and the problem will be solved. The other issue still open now, unrelated to this question though, is how Ubuntu 12.04 is handling dual video carded laptops. I'll try and play with that too and post another question later on.

Answer (score 0):

With modern operating systems a standard called ACPI is used by an operating system to control power use, hibernation and suspension, fans, thermal control and so on. Some time during boot the operating system uses ACPI information to take over control of these matters from the computers BIOS. It might be worthwhile to try to leave control of this to the BIOS to test whether that helps.

Perhaps the easiest way to test this would be to choose acpi=off while using a recent Ubuntu live cd. From the initial Ubuntu menu immediately after booting and selecting your language you can use F6 and select this from the pop up menu.

Then you should be able to listen for the fan speed and feel if the computer grows as hot.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to mine is bumblebee. Nvidia does not yet has a solution for it's optimus feature on linux, so the latter is the best solution, or better yet, a 'workaround' as I have read. Correct me if I am wrong. Here's [the link](http://bumblebee-project.org).

Comment: With respect to the great effort put by the developers, I must say I don't think that this simple workaround will have a far future with the complex graphics cards it will have to deal with continuously. NVidia should better support their own gear under Linux. One fine day... :)